# Call SQLCLR from trigger or polling?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a table that will receive messages from a 3rd party software, I need a triggering mechanism to call my dotnet code.  What are are the pros and cons of a trigger calling a SQLCLR which then could call a web service for example vs just having my code poll the table for changes. Is suspect the average load of the table will be very little, maybe a few thousand transactions a day.

Comment: Always avoid polling when possible. Why not use a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of SQL Server you're using, but if it's 2005+, [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) was made for this. In your trigger, put a (short) message on the queue. Have your service execute a WAITFOR on the queue which will then trigger a RECIEVE to grab the message. Better than spinning cycles seeing if there's nothing to do.

Comment: The version is 2005, I was hesitant of the service broker as from what I read it was a bit more complicated to setup is this not the case?

Comment: While there are some gotchas, it's not as bad as all that. Going forward, more and more features in the SQL Server product are implemented with service broker. You'd do yourself a favor in learning it. :)

Answer (score 3):

I, personally, would *never* call a web service in a trigger. I would write a service that polls the table for new data and calls the web service asynchronously.

The main issue is that if you are calling the web service in a trigger then you can get into situations whereby you are keeping locks open for a long time. If that lock has been escalated to a table lock then you are blocking all operations on the table for the duration.

It also doesn't leave you with a very good retry strategy should your call to the web service fail for whatever reason. Do you expect your trigger to somehow mark the rows for retry later? What would trigger that retry?

With a service based approach, you keep it far simpler, and with much less chance of running into locking issues - which can be tricky to diagnose at the best of times - particularly if they are transient.

Comment: +1 Calling long-running and by principle unreliable externals from a trigger makes me nervous.